# Stored Procedure Vs Normal SQL Query in Latest MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I would like to know whether there is any performance benefit in using the stored procedure in the latest MySQL ?

As Normal SQL also works like stored procedure since the db does Syntax checking, Plan is selected, Compiled and cached.

What are the benefits with the recent version? Since still few companies are using stored procedure mostly.

Thanks In Advance,
Kathir

Comment: There is a performance benefit even with the recent version, but it's a debatable question to say the least. To sproc or not to sproc.

Comment: If the DB server is going to be a different server than the application server (which will be the usual case) then the stored procedure is faster than the normal queries since the performance or faster depends on the network latency/network slowness/ network bandwidth and the turn around time for the request and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much performance difference when the DB and App Server are local. There are performance differences when the DB and App Server are in different places which is a normal case.